# Chromecast SDK Android: getApplicationMetadata returns null

Tags: android, google-cast, chromecast

In my sender app I'm using

```
ApplicationMetadata metadata = Cast.CastApi.getApplicationMetadata(apiClient);
```

while

```
apiClient.isConnected()
```

returns true and my receiver app is running on the Chromecast.
When I do this, the method always returns null so the metadata object is always set to null.
Is there anything else I need to do for this to work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a bug there which will be addressed in the next release. Meanwhile, note that when you call `Cast.CastApi.launchApplication()` or `Cast.CastApi.joinApplication()`, you get a `PendingResult` object. You can set a callback on that to be notified of the result of your call; the  `onResult()` method will be called and an `ApplicationConnectionResult` object will be passed to it. You can call `getApplicationMetadata()` on that object and that works fine (assuming you successfully launch or join an application).

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I'm aware of that thanks. :) I was just looking of a way to find out which application was running at any given time without joining a session.